# How to obtain the red, green and blue values from gray value in java?

Tags: java, image

I obtain the gray value of the pixel by :

```
val=img.getRGB(j, i) & 0xFF;
```

for processing purpose.

Now , after processing I want the red, green and blue values back. How do I do this?

Comment: Save the initial value in a separate variable or re-extract it. I'm not sure how your line of code gets "the gray value" though. That looks to maybe get the alpha value and nothing else.

Comment: okay. will try to do this

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code to obtain the r, g, b, alpha, and gray-scale values for a pixel at coordinates (x, y) on a `BufferedImage`.

```
BufferedImage image;          // assume you have this image
int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y); // get the desired pixel
int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF; 
int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (rgb & 0xFF);
int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF; 
int gray = (r + g + b) / 3; // rgb are not affected
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below:-

```
int r=(rgb>>16) & 0xff; 
int g=(rgb>>8) & 0xff;
int b=(rgb) & 0xff;
```

where `int rgb=img.getRGB(j, i);`

Store these values for later retrieval.
Refer: [RGB values of an image](http://hrboyceiii.blogspot.in/2007/02/bit-shifting-what-is-it-and-why.html)

In case of a gray image:-

```
int rgb = (val << 16) | (val << 8) | (val << 0);
```

You can get the rgb value of gray image like above, and then apply the methods of finding r,g and b as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Check my edit. Hope that answers your question. I am assuming that you want the r,g and b values of your new gray value i.e. val.